# Yii restful API, how to modify return results from model

Tags: php, api, rest, yii, yii2

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=6) to set up my back end server based on Yii framework and then [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) to set up my API and everything is working as it should. 
But I am not sure how to accomplish the next step:
My return array right now is pulling records that look like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "user_id": 1,
 "description": "This is a summary of article 1",
 "status": 2,
 "type": 1,
 "created_at": 1426210780,
 "updated_at": 1426365319
}
```

The value for 'type' is '1' in the db, but I want to store all the possible values of 'type' in another table like this:

```
 1 : Red
 2 : Blue
 3 : Green
```

And then I want the JSON returned via my API to contain "type":'red' instead of "type":1. I assume I need to override something in my Model, but I can't figure out what to override or with what.

I'm happy to read through tutorials or documentation but I'm such a beginner at this that I'm not sure what terms to search for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at models and their relationships to other models, this will allow you to get the information you need.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Once the relationship is working correctly you should be able to get the colour from the original model.

Although this is from a earlier version of Yii it may help you understand how the models will interact as well
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models/

Comment: Thanks, this information is helpful. I'm a little wary of not knowing what is different for 2.0 but I guess there just isn't a wealth of documentation and tutorials out there yet on 2.0.

Comment: Okay, I've followed that documentation and actually found the 2.0 documentation, too. I've set up the models and relationships and I can now successfully use getTypeName in the view and display 'red' as the type. 
But the API is not using a view, it is (I think) using the findOne() method and echoing the results back. There is no place for me to put getTypeName into. How do I modify the default function (findOne?) so when I pull a 'report' via API, I don't return 'type' as 1 but instead 'type' as 'red'?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

@Burrito's response provided documentation but I want to give the full solution for other searchers:

First, I needed to set up a model for 'Type'.

Second, I needed to declare the relationship between 'Report' (my main model) and 'Type' like this (in my Report model):

```
public function getType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Type::className(), ['id' => 'type']);
}
```

(I'm not sure if that step is necessary, but the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data) makes it seem necessary.)

Third, I created getTypeName (in Report model), to get the name of the type based on the ID:

```
public function getTypeName($type = null)
{
    return Type::findOne($type)->name;
}
```

Lastly, in my apiController, I modified the function that I am using to get all records to include a loop for each record that called getTypeName:

```
protected function findAllReports()
{
    // get all reports
    $reports = Report::find()
                ->asArray()
                ->all();

    if( $reports ){
        $i = 0; 
        // loop through each report
        foreach($reports as $report){
            $model = new Report();
            // add a new key/value pair to each report array, populate with getTypeName and pass the type ID to it as a parameter
            $reports[$i]['typeName'] = $model->getTypeName($reports[$i]['type']);
            $i++;
        }
        return $reports;
    } else {
       // error or no results
    }
}
```

For reference, the other routine needed here is the action that the API hits, which calls findAllReports():

```
public function actionList()
{
    $reports=$this->findAllReports();
    $this->setHeader(200);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'data'=>$reports),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Finally, now if I called [url]/api/list, I get an array of reports, including the typeName.